# Chrome not jumping to fragment identifier / anchor

Tags: html, google-chrome

This is such a simple thing I'm having a hard time grokking what could be going wrong.   In one web page, a link with a fragment:

```
<a href='https://strenga.com/about-strenga/#faq'>FAQ</a>
```

In the web page in question, an anchor:

```
<section id="faq"><h2>Frequently Asked Questions<h2>...</section>
```

From my windows machine, clicking on the link correctly jumps to the target anchor in Edge and IE, but doesn't in a current version Chrome or Firefox.  (Oddly enough, it seems to work from Chrome on a mobile device.)

Additional observations:

- After clicking on the link above, the url bar in Chrome displays the url without the fragment identifier (i.e. in the case above it shows `https://strenga.com/about-strenga/`)
- If you enter the url directly into the url bar on Chrome (rather than clicking on a link), the same behavior happens, *unless* you are already on the page (e.g. while on page `foo.com`, enter `foo.com/#fragment`), in which case it jumps properly.
- It does seem to be specific to my web-page: visiting a URL with a fragment on other sites (for example Stack Overflow) works just fine.

I could understand this if the page were dynamically assembled (maybe the anchor isn't present in DOM when the browser looks, or maybe it doesn't have the layout figured out yet), but this is a static page with nothing complicated going on.

There are some other SO posts, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467363/external-anchor-link-doesnt-work-in-chrome) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588927/1539989) that suggest "working around a Chrome bug", but I'd expect if Chrome had a bug of this magnitude, you could find it on their site.  Continuing my digging, I did find these plausibly relevant:

- [Losing fragment identifiers with re-directs](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24175)
- [a Windows 10/Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516349) that has since been fixed.

However, I know (and verified in Chrome devtools) that the url in question is not being re-directed, and I've gone through the steps in that Win10/Chrome bug to verify that their fix is in place on my machine.

What else could I possibly be doing that screws this up?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was javascript.  Buried in the javascript code was a rewrite to the url:

```
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var value = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  window.history.replaceState("blog", "Blog", value );
}
```

That code was to clean up query parameters, but also would get the fragment identifier.   In hindsight it seems like something I would have caught easier, but the code was deeply buried and not relevant to this page.

My own code, so not much of a general answer, except: look carefully at your javascript... :-)